# Long press to drag and drop ionic list with ionic.bundle.js v1.2.4

Tags: css, angularjs, sorting, ionic-framework, drag-and-drop

As per my requirement, I want to implement long press to drag and drop ionic list items.

I am using v1.2.4 ionic.bundle.js

I am following this link for drag and drop: http://blog.scottlogic.com/alee/assets/ionic-sorter/new/index.html

The above example uses ionic.bundle.js v1.0.0.beta-13.

If I try to run the same example with ionic.bundle.js v1.2.4, its not working fine.

Please give your suggestions.

Comment: Hello, can you give us more details please? "its not working fine" is not enough. What do you call not working fine? Do you have any errors on console? What is the exact behavior? Thank you.

Comment: "its not working fine" means when you try the same example with latest ionic bundle, on longpress scroll issue occurs, will attach the fiddle for the same.